# R: Specify output saving name in functions

Tags: r, function, output

I am trying to specify the output file within my function, is this possible in R?

X is my dataset, for instance Indexreturns$marketreturn
As Z I would then like to specify how I want to call my output and send it to a tex file.

My function is as follows:

```
ProcessIndexReturns <- function(x,z){
  z <- describe.by(x,group=Indexreturns$group)
  x <- describe(x)
  z <- rbindlist(z)
  z <- rbind(z,x)
  z <- z[c(1,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,2,3,12),c(4,3)]
  z <- z %>%
    mutate(Sharpe = (12*mean)/(sqrt(12)*sd)) %>%
    mutate(`Equity Premium `= 12*mean*100) %>%
    mutate(sd = sqrt(12)*sd*100) %>%
    select(-mean)

  z <- z[,c(2,3,1)]
  row.names(z) <- c("1820","1830","1840","1850","1860","1870","1880","1890","1900","1910","1920","Full Sample")
  print(xtable(z, type = "latex"), file = "z.tex")
}
```

If I insert X and Z, I want to receive a data.table called z and an output file called "z".tex